# Why is my thead not appearing in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have made a table with a `thead` (header); on a Mac, and in Firefox everything is fine, but on Internet Explorer 6 the head is just gone...

Any idea why?

Here is the link to test it: http://www.acecrodeo.com/new/05-rodeos.php... The table is constructed in `tablerize.js`:

```
jQuery.fn.tablerize = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var table;
        $(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
            var values = $(this).html().split('*');
            if(i == 0) {
                table = $('<table>');
                var thead = $('<thead>');
                $.each(values, function(y) {
                    thead.append($('<th>').html(values[y]));
                });
                table.append(thead);
            } else {
               var tr = $('<tr>');
               $.each(values, function(y) {
                   tr.append($('<td>').html(values[y]));
               });
               table.append(tr);
            }
        });
        $(this).after(table).remove();
    });
};
```

...from a list on the page:

```
<ul>

<li>&nbsp; Date*Endroit*Sanction</li>
<li>&nbsp; 29 Mars &amp; 5 Avril*St-&Eacute;variste, Beauce&nbsp; # 1*&Eacute;quipe Rod&eacute;o du Qc.</li>
<li>&nbsp; 12 &amp; 19 Avril*St-&Eacute;variste, Beauce&nbsp; # 2*&Eacute;quipe Rod&eacute;o du Qc.</li>
<!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't find any THEAD at all in the code...

Comment: The table is built by JS from a list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well since I'm the author of tablerize I might as well fix it.

```
jQuery.fn.tablerize = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var table = $('<table>');
        var tbody = $('<tbody>');
        $(this).find('li').each(function(i) {
            var values = $(this).html().split('*');
            if(i == 0) {
                var thead = $('<thead>');
                var tr = $('<tr>');
                $.each(values, function(y) {
                    tr.append($('<th>').html(values[y]));
                });
                table.append(thead.append(tr));
            } else {
               var tr = $('<tr>');
               $.each(values, function(y) {
                   tr.append($('<td>').html(values[y]));
               });
               tbody.append(tr);
            }
        });
        $(this).after(table.append(tbody)).remove();
    });
};
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 6):

You're including `<th>` elements directly in the `<thead>` group; that's not actually legal. You must enclose them in a `<tr>` element, and put *that* in the `<thead>`...

See: [11.2.3 Row groups: the THEAD, TFOOT, and TBODY elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3)

So modify `jQuery.fn.tablerize()`to insert a `<tr>` within the `<thead>` before appending the `<th>` elements:

```
table = $('<table>');
var thead = $('<thead>');
var headRow = $('<tr>');
$.each(values, function(y) {
      headRow.append($('<th>').html(values[y]));
   });
thead.append(headRow);
table.append(thead);
```

Note that you're also omitting the `<tbody>` element; you should probably put the rest of the rows in one of those as well.